# Ubuntu 20.04 gnumeric 1.12.46 displays unicode boxes from older gnumeric files

Tags: display, gnumeric

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and just discovered all my old gnumric files do not display correctly.  All text and numeric fields in the spreadsheet show up as hex codes in little boxes, like some programs do with unicode characters.  But, if I click on that cell, it displays correctly in the editing window.  Also, the hex code is the normal character, so a capital A shows as 0041, for instance.  Is there a setting I need to make in gnumeric to make these fields display as normal text?  I note that more recent gnumeric files display fine.

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I see that if I go to a cell and change the font size, it now displays properly.

Comment: Ahh, more info, only fields that are using Courier font are not displaying properly.  Files set to Sans are fine.

Comment: OK the problem is that the courier truetype font is not installed on this system.  I finally got the ttf-mscorefonts-installer to work, and it did "something" but still no courier font.  When I use font manager I get the same boxes in the sample display for courier and courier 10 pitch.  I can go into all the spreadsheets and select mutiple cells and change the font to sans, or courier new, and it is then fine, but this is a lot of manual work to change many spreadsheets.  So, the

Comment: issue is that existing spreadsheets specify "courier" and not "courier new".  Is there a way to make gnumeric know to use courier new instead of courier?  I have tried making symbolic links and copying .ttf files with different names, but none of that worked.

Comment: Well, fiddling with font stuff, "Courier" shows up properly in gnome-font-viewer, but displays as blocks in font-manager.  I don't know what that means.  And, of course, it displays as the blocks in gnumeric.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have resolved my problem, but not "solved" it.  The problem is that I could not install a "Courier" font that gnumeric could use.
"Courier New" was fine, but old spreadsheets created under the gnumeric version from Ubuntu 12.04 or so used Courier font, and that was not available under the Ubuntu 20.04 system.
My fix was to copy the old .gnumerc file to a .gz file extension, then gunzip the file, and use sed to change all "Courier" ocurrences to "Courier New", then gzip the file, change file extension back to .gnumeric!  I created a script to do this on all the files.  Saved me hours of work.